# Xcode 4.3.3 IPhone 5.1 Simulator hanging every so often

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash, ios-simulator

I've been looking around to see if anyone has similar issues recently but can't find much info.

Most of the time launching apps in simulator works fine. But once or twice a day the simulator hangs and I have to force quit it. XCode says 'Running xyz on simulator'. When you try and 'Stop' in XCode nothing happens. I then have to force quit XCode.

The annoying thing is the simulator wont work again unless I restart the machine!

This never happens when I run apps directly on iPhone. It has happened on several occasions for me both with sample apps and my own.

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me but not recently (I stayed on 4.3.2). That said, Xcode 4.4 will be released today (almost for sure, as Mt Lion is coming out today). Get it and see if problem goes away!

EDIT: I did upgrade to 4.4, then 4.5, then 4.6. I have not had a single hang, using several machines, and neither has my coworkers, since leaving 4.3. YMMV of course.

Comment: Hope so its quite annoying but I think it might be something to do with having my iPhone connected and then running the simulator. Just guessing but I can seem to reproduce it that way.

Comment: Everyone I know that does serious development has to force Xcode 4.3 to quit and restart at least once a day. Having to reboot was a big problem for me on I think 4.3.1 but went away in 4.3.2

Comment: Go to connect.apple.com and you can download it from there. I just did.

Comment: Ok so latest Xcode doesn't really help I guess thats just XCode then.

Comment: So you are on the latest version of Lion? Have you run Disk Utility and verified your disk? Have you "Repaired Permissions"? Are you sure some old simulator is not getting launched?

Comment: latest Xcode, not on lion yet. Will try again with ML once i install and will try disk perms etc. I doubt its disk perms though, its a brand new retina macbook pro.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Edit Scheme -> Use GDB Debugger instead of LLDB - this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This has frustrated me for -years- now but stumbled across what appears to get things going again for me:

Hide the simulator (iOS Simulator -> Hide iOS Simulator) or Cmd-H, then reopen the simulator.

The problem seems to happen when something CPU intensive is happening in the background (like a Time Machine backup) on my old 2 core MacBook.

Comment: Thanks i'll try it again nxt time it happens, I don't think its a resource issue as i'm using a retina mbp.

Comment: I also have a core 2 macbook and this worked for me.  How on earth did you figure that out?? :)  Regardless - thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

the issue was [reported](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4160869?tstart=0) to apple support communities today.

Comment: doesn't happen every time for me just sometimes. Surely it can't be that hard for them to fix.

Answer (score 0):

you can do reset contents and settings of iphone simulator than check it..
sometimes if we run so much application in simulator and not reset it than this kind of problem is occurs.